# Is it legal to issue private road notices on public estates in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, privacy, real-estate, vehicle, motor-vehicle

This morning I parked my car around the corner in a new housing estate and walked to work. When I got back to my car, I found this stuck on the windshield...

[image]

The housing estate is completely new and openly accessible to its residents and their visitors. There are no explicit signs illustrating that the estate is private, and unless I'm wrong, non-private roads and pavements belong to the local council?

What I would like to know is:

- What is the likeliness of roads supporting a new build development being private?
- How do I find out who actually owns the roads and pavements?
- Would leasehold vs. freehold land have an impact?
- Is this notice enforceable by law?

As per Geoff Atkin's comment, this is in Liverpool, England.

Comment: One key point regarding enforceability is whether you're in England & Wales or Scotland. Scottish law has more restrictions as to what can be done about vehicles illegally parked on private land.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins thank you. I've amended the question in response.

Comment: More and more these days new estates aren't having their roads adopted by the local council, and instead remain the property of and responsibility of the developer.  So while it's a public estate, as in the public lives there, the roads may very well be private property and only for the use of the estates dwellers.